# mysql select / insert into same table

Tags: mysql, select

My table :

```
num_id      name      date1         item
1           Bill      2015-01-01   item1
2           Bill      2015-01-01   item2
```

I'm trying to create a stored procedure so if the user creates a new entry into the table with a NEW date, all existing records with the same `NAME` are copied.  So if a record for `Bill` is created with date `2016-01-01`, records for `item1` and `item2` are created, so the table would look like :

```
num_id      name      date1         item
1           Bill      2015-01-01   item1
2           Bill      2015-01-01   item2 
3           Bill      2016-01-01   item1
4           Bill      2016-01-01   item2
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: have you considered splitting your table into two, one with `num_id`, `name` and `date1`, and the other with the `item`s?

Comment: Hello Kostas, yes that is actually the way I have it setup.  I simplified my example to try and make it more understandable.  The record is added to the date1 table by the user (2016-01-01 in my example.  I then want to find all the detail (item) records from the item table for the previous date (2015-01-01).

Answer (score 0):

This is also a way to do it

```
insert into mytable (
    select NULL,name,date1,item
    FROM mytable where name = 'Bill'
    ) as tmp;
```